# Biztalk Cannot process EDIFACT file

Tags: biztalk, edifact

I'm new in processing EDIFACT files. I want to process a EDIFACT file of type D:01B INTFSTA. I searched for schema in BizTalk server, created orchestration and deployed in BizTalk server. While processing the file I get the following error.

Error encountered during parsing.

Error: 1 (Miscellaneous error)
    70: Cannot locate document specification because multiple schemas matched the message type "http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/EDI/EDIFACT/2006#EFACT_D01B_IFTSTA".

Error: 2 (Miscellaneous error)
    71: Transaction Set or Group Control Number Mismatch

Error: 3 (Miscellaneous error)
    29: Invalid count specified at interchange, group or message level

.
 The sequence number of the suspended message is 1.

There is no other application using the same schema (D:01B INTFSTA).

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you have the schema deployed more than once in your BizTalk environment. In the BizTalk console, go to "`All Artifacts`", select "`Schemas`" and list alphabetically. There, search for `EFACT_D01B_IFTSTA` in the Root Name column. You will find that it is deployed in another application most likely.

A good practice around deploying EDI schemas btw, is to update the namespace to include the name of your trading partner. More than 1 of your trading partners may use the schema in different ways or have customizations in it. This approach lets you handle this situation.

The suggested namespace would, for example, be `http://schemas.yourcompany.com/partners/yourtradingpartner`

Answer (score 0):

1. Most likely, the schema is not deployed.  Check the Schemas node of the All Artifacts Application.

2&3. You test EDIFACT instance is invalid.  Did you cut and paste it together?  That would cause the mis-matches.

Note, it's a better practice to change the Target Namespace on the EDI schemas to something specific to the app which uses them.